# $n$ is divisor of $a-b$ if and only if $n$ is a divisor of $b-a$

Tags: divisibility

I am asked to show that $n$ is divisor of $a-b$ if and only if $n$ is a divisor of $b-a$

It may seem trivial but I am struggling with this question.
I am trying to proof it by using the definition but I am struggling.
The answer I have is that this question is trivial but I would really appreciate it if you guys could give me hand.
Thanks.

Comment: What definitions are you aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a-b)$ is divisible by $n$ if and if $a-b=kn$ for some integer $k$.

This implies $b-a=-(a-b)=(-k)\cdot n$. This means $(b-a)$ is divisible by $n$.

Does that help?

Comment: OwO what's this? :3c

Comment: @TundraFizz Anything wrong?

Comment: Nope looks good to me 

Comment: i need to have more confidence in myself, that's exaclty what i wrote. thanks for your time

Comment: Writing $b-a=-(a-b) = -(kn) = (-k)n$ would be clearer.

Comment: @Ihf That was a good suggection. Done the editing.